# Draw oval using Leafletjs Draw Library

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, leaflet

I am trying to draw oval and Circle using Leafletjs Draw library, it works fine but the problem is the Circle boundary doesn't touch with the Mouse pointer on mousemove. here is the code and fiddle.

try to draw the oval you will observe the mouse pointer is not touching the circle boundary

https://jsfiddle.net/Lscupxqp/12/

```
var points = [L.GeoJSON.latLngToCoords(this._startLatLng),L.GeoJSON.latLngToCoords(latlng)];

            var x = Math.abs(points[1][0] - points[0][0]);
            var y = Math.abs(points[1][1] - points[0][1]);


            var x_percent, y_percent;
            x_percent = y_percent = 1;

            //show in %
            if(x < y) {
                x_percent = x / y;
            }
            else {

                y_percent = y / x;
            }

            this._drawShape(latlng);

            this._shape.rx = x_percent;
            this._shape.ry = y_percent;
```

GetPathString method

```
 getPathString: function () {
    var p = this._point,
        r = this._radius;

    if (this._checkIfEmpty()) {
      return '';
    }

    //console.log(this);

    if (L.Browser.svg) {
      var rr = 'M' + p.x + ',' + (p.y - r) + 'A' + (r * this.rx) + ',' + (r * this.ry) + ',0,1,1,' + (p.x - 0.1) + ',' + (p.y - r) + ' z';

      return rr;
    } else {
      p._round();
      r = Math.round(r);

      return 'AL ' + p.x + ',' + p.y + ' ' + r + ',' + r + ' 0,' + (65535 * 360);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I see in your fiddle that circle center is not stable but moving along vertical (meridional) line. Should it be pinned it when mouse is down? What function draws your circle and what are parameters?

Comment: @MBo Circle is SVG based the function above in my code draw the circle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I've got your mistake - change `(p.y - r)` to `(p.y - r * this.ry)` :

```
if (L.Browser.svg) {
      var rr = 'M' + p.x + ',' + (p.y - r * this.ry) + 
      'A' + (r * this.rx) + ',' + (r * this.ry) + ',0,0,0,' + p.x  + ',' + (p.y + r * this.ry) + 
      'A' + (r * this.rx) + ',' + (r * this.ry) + ',0,1,0,' + (p.x) + ',' + (p.y - r * this.ry) +' z';
```